# How to calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty}y^{2}e^{-y(x+1)}dy$?

Tags: calculus, probability

I want to evaluate the following integral in a question I had in Probability:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}y^{2}e^{-y(x+1)}dy
$$
But I'm stuck figuring out how to solve this integral. How to calculate this integral?

Comment: Do you know the PDF, mean, and variance of an exponential distribution? If so, this question becomes very easy.

Comment: @Clarinetist It's likely that the reason OP wants to know how to compute this integral is in order to calculate the variance of an exponential distribution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without using exponential distribution shortcuts,
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}y^2e^{-y(x + 1)}\text{ d}y = \lim_{t \to \infty}\int_{0}^{t}y^2e^{-y(x + 1)}\text{ d}y\text{.}$$
We then integrate by parts twice.

For the first time, let $u_1 = y^2$ and $\text{d}v_1 = e^{-y(x+1)}\text{ d}y$, so that
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{t}y^2e^{-y(x + 1)}\text{ d}y &= \left.\dfrac{y^2}{-(x+1)}e^{-y(x+1)}\right|_{0}^{t} - \int_{0}^{t}\dfrac{e^{-y(x+1)}}{-(x+1)}\cdot 2y\text{ d}y \\
&= \dfrac{-t^2}{x+1}e^{-t(x+1)}+\dfrac{2}{x+1}\int_{0}^{t}ye^{-y(x+1)}\text{ d}y
\end{align}$$
Now, for the integral $\int_{0}^{t}ye^{-y(x+1)}\text{ d}y$, we set $u_2 = y$ and $\text{d}v_2 = e^{-y(x+1)}\text{ d}y$, so that
$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{t}ye^{-y(x+1)}\text{ d}y &= \left.\dfrac{y}{-(x+1)}e^{-y(x+1)}\right|_{0}^{t} - \int_{0}^{t}\dfrac{e^{-y(x+1)}}{-(x+1)}\text{ d}y \\
&= \dfrac{t}{-(x+1)}e^{-t(x+1)}+\dfrac{1}{x+1}\int_{0}^{t}e^{-y(x+1)}\text{ d}y \\
&= \dfrac{t}{-(x+1)}e^{-t(x+1)}+\dfrac{1}{(x+1)^2}\left[1-e^{-t(x+1)}\right]
\end{align}$$
Thus we obtain
$$\int_{0}^{t}y^2e^{-y(x+1)}\text{ d}y = \dfrac{-t^2}{x+1}e^{-t(x+1)}+\dfrac{2}{x+1}\left\{ \dfrac{t}{-(x+1)}e^{-t(x+1)}+\dfrac{1}{(x+1)^2}\left[1-e^{-t(x+1)}\right]\right\}$$
and taking the limit as $t \to \infty$,
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}y^2e^{-y(x+1)}\text{ d}y = \dfrac{2}{x+1}\left[\dfrac{1}{(x+1)^2}\right] = \dfrac{2}{(x+1)^3}\text{.}$$

---

With exponential distribution shortcuts, write
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}y^2e^{-y(x+1)}\text{ d}y = \int_{0}^{\infty}z^2e^{-z(x+1)}\text{ d}z = \dfrac{1}{x+1}\int_{0}^{\infty}z^2 \cdot (x+1)e^{-z(x+1)}\text{ d}z$$
and one will recognize that the above integral has a part which is the PDF of an exponential distribution with mean $\frac{1}{x+1}$: namely $f(z) = (x+1)e^{-z(x+1)}$ for $z > 0$.

So,
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}z^2 \cdot (x+1)e^{-z(x+1)}\text{ d}z = \int_{0}^{\infty}z^2f(z)\text{ d}z$$
is $\mathbb{E}[Z^2]$, where $Z$ follows an exponential distribution with mean $\mathbb{E}[Z] = \dfrac{1}{x+2}$.

Thus, one may recall that $\text{Var}(Z) = \dfrac{1}{(x+2)^2}$, so
$$\mathbb{E}[Z^2] = \text{Var}(Z) + (\mathbb{E}[Z])^2 = \dfrac{1}{(x+2)^2} + \dfrac{1}{(x+2)^2} = \dfrac{2}{(x+2)^2}$$
thus
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}y^2e^{-y(x+1)}\text{ d}y = \dfrac{1}{x+1} \cdot \mathbb{E}[Z^2] = \dfrac{2}{(x+1)^3}$$

Comment: You are awesome

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $x+1 > 0$, do a change of variables $y = t/(x+1)$ and use the definition of the
Gamma function.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha=(x+1)y$, then
$$\int_0^{\infty}y^2 e^{-(x+1)y}dy = \dfrac{1}{(x+1)^3}\int_0^{+\infty}\alpha^2e^{-\alpha}d\alpha=\dfrac{2}{(x+1)^3}$$